# grease pencil as raster

Tags: grease-pencil

How to set grease pencil to draw as raster ? if i'm doing fast curve stroke, i hate when blender convert it into segmented curve (stepping curve). Is it possible to have a smooth line like doing a sketch using raster app like sketchable etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Drawing Mode > Active Window and Workspace Settings > Options,

Turning up the "input samples" to a higher number works. Also switching on the "Post Processing Settings" and adding more Subdivision Steps should help as well.

[image: Brush stroke options]

Answer (score 1):

The way Grease Pencil works is in Vector form using the structure mentioned in Blender Manual here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/structure.html

[image]

You can play with Post Processing settings:
[image]

Also you can Press `Shift` key while drawing. This will give you smooth (stabilized)
lines.
Learn more about this here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modes/draw/tool_settings/draw.html?highlight=stabilizer